# How to find the probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

John invites 12 people to a dinner party, half of which are men. Exactly one man and one woman are bringing desserts. If one person from this group is selected at random,what is the probability that it is a woman, or a man who is not bringing a dessert?

Comment: From how many of the $12$ you can say that it is a woman or one of the men who are not bringing a desert?

Comment: Thats exactly what is bugging me!

Answer (score 2):

There are $6+5=11$ persons of the $12$ that fall in one of the classes: 1) women 2) men that do not bring a desert. So the probability is $\frac{11}{12}$.

(If the first class is meant to be: women that do not bring a desert, then there are $5+5=10$ persons and the probability is $\frac{10}{12}$)

Comment: Please explain it elaborately. How did you find that the sample set is 6+5=11?

Comment: Do you agree that $6$ of the $12$ persons are women and that $5$ of them are men that do not bring a desert? If one person of the $12$ is randomly selected then there is a chance of $\frac{11}{12}$ that he/she falls in one these categories (i.e. satisfies the prescription: 'is a woman or is a man that is not bringing a desert').

Comment: Can you do it via the formula P(AUB)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A interesection B)?

Comment: In principle yes, but the intersection is empty here. It resulst in: $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=\frac{6}{12}+\frac{5}{12}-0=\frac{11}{12}$

Comment: So, what would have been the answer if the question asked 'and' in place of 'or'? How would you approach the problem?

Comment: The probability that a man (bringing a desert) **and** a woman are selected is $0$ if only **one** person is selected. There are no persons who are a man **and** a woman as well.

Answer (score -2):

I could be wrong, but I would have said that 10 people didn't bring deserts so we are looking at a 1/10 probability?